# Cannot get HashMap class from Class.forName()

Tags: kotlin

I want to get `HashMap<String, View>` class with the help of method `Class.forName()` and use it in KotlinPoet. I do it in the following way:

```
PropertySpec.builder("viewMap", Class.forName("kotlin.collections.MutableMap<String, View>"))
            .initializer(CodeBlock.of("hashMapOf()"))
            .build()
```

But when I build the app I got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.collections.MutableMap<String, View>
```

What's the matter of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Java isn't aware of generics at runtime. As far as Java cares, the name of your class is `kotlin.collections.MutableMap`. Consider

```
Class.forName("kotlin.collections.MutableMap")
```

Comment: And just to clarify, since Kotlin runs on the JVM it has the same "problem" as Java regarding generics.

Comment: @Silvio, same issue when I remove generic. `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.collections.MutableMap`

Answer (score 2):

`MutableMap` is a *mapped type*, which is translated by the compiler into a different type in the bytecode.

A more familiar example is `kotlin.Any` (and `kotlin.Any?`), which are translated into `java.lang.Object` when compiled for the JVM.  The source code is all written in terms of `Any`, but the bytecode knows nothing about that, only about `Object`.  (And of course, when compiled for other platforms, which don't have `java.lang.Object`, different mappings are used.)

It looks like you've hit another of these.  Kotlin/JVM compiles any reference to `kotlin.collections.MutableMap` (and `kotlin.collections.Map`) into `java.util.Map`.  That's why Java reflection knows nothing about those Kotlin types: they just don't exist at runtime.

(This is yet another reason why reflection should be treated with caution.  I see many questions relating to it — perhaps from developers used to more dynamic languages where it's more appropriate.  But in Kotlin/Java it tends to be inefficient, awkward, long-winded, fragile, and insecure; it's hard to do safely, and needs a lot more manual handling of errors that normally the compiler would be able to catch — as this question shows.  Reflection is a powerful and necessary tool for frameworks, plug-ins, build tools, and suchlike; but for general application coding, in my experience it's almost never needed and there's almost always a better approach.)